# "Transform" code from an AutoRun.inf file

Tags: windows-7, usb, encryption, inf, veracrypt

I've recently been fiddling with VeraCrypt and wanted to encrypt a USB-drive. VeraCrypt has a very handy portable future, so you can encrypt the drive and include the Veracrypt software so you can decrypt it whenever and wherever you plug the USB-stick in. Unfortunately since Windows 7 there is no longer any support for the AutoRun feature on USB-sticks. So the AutoRun.inf file is basically useless.

My question is, can I transform the code in the .inf file into something for an .exe or .bat file (really not that knowledgeable about this kind of stuff) so I can have a single file that will still run through the whole process of decrypting withouth me having to open the program an go through the necesarry steps myself?

[Screenshot of the autorun.inf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRUJY.png)

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to run the "open=" command when you want to start it, and the "shell/dismount/command=" when you want to stop/dismount it.

<sub>*[PS. Next time, just copy & paste the actual text from a notepad file, no need for a screenshot of text]*</sub>

So maybe a batch file for *each* of the commands would work - basically just a file in notepad with the one line, and named "start.bat" & "dismount.bat". I'm not too sure if "start" needs both lines, or just one, but you can test in a command prompt/terminal.

start.bat:

```
VeraCrypt/VeraCrypt.exe /q background /e /m rm /v "KeePass"
VeraCrypt/VeraCrypt.exe
```

dismount.bat:

```
VeraCrypt/VeraCrypt.exe /q /d
```